# How to Submit a login page of external Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to log in on external application by bypassing its login page.

Scenario is :
User logged in on Mobilefirst application on iOS/ Android device. This has been authenticated from AD (Active Directoy).
Now he clicks on a link of an external application which is on a different domain and has a login page. But this is also lined with the same AD.
I want to call that application without entering username/pswd again on its login page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario asked is possible if during authentication (within the SecurityCheck), Active Directory returns a cookie or a token that will identify this user. 
If there is such an option, this token can be sent to the client when MFP authentication completes at the security check.

Later , when you are accessing the external application link, you can pass on the token/value received earlier and that should technically log you in ( if it is valid and not expired).If it is accepted in a specific header, this header and its value can be set when making the request to external application.

All this is subject to the presence of such a token and how it can be passed.

Comment: Thanks viven, but when we open external application url we use window.open so passing this token this way be ok ?

Comment: In that case, we need to see if we can add headers to the request that open in window.open

Comment: can I submit a form through my hybrid application with post option. currently we are submitting only login form none other than that.